# Video feed not working - "qbvideochat_p2pIsNotPossible"

Tags: quickblox

So I just started working with QB and am trying to implement the videochat. I took the code from their sample and modified it a bit. I'm able to connect two devices with sound, but nothing appears for video. I did notice this message in the logs:

```
    -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendMessage:] -> Message: <message id="101027544" 
    type="qbvideochat_p2pIsNotPossible" to="1040156-9755@chat.quickblox.com" 
from="1039653-9755@chat.quickblox.com">
<extraParams xmlns=""><sessionID>421051409.487072
</sessionID><callType>1</callType></extraParams></message>
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with it::`qbvideochat_p2pIsNotPossible`. But otherwise I have no idea.

Comment: have you find any solution ? i got same problem.so i need your help for that.

Comment: @VishalGandhi Sorry Vishal, I was only testing QB out and didn't continue with it.

Answer (score 0):

**qbvideochat_p2pIsNotPossible** is not related to video or audio, it means that you have a chat through relay server, not p2p. It's OK

Does origin video chat sample works OK?

Comment: So, it's been working today most of the time. I'm not sure if I had the UIImageViews not quite hooked up right or if it was something to do with the network quality... I need to perform further testing though.